# There to put an infinity loop which is able to change a TextView?

Tags: java, android, loops, kotlin

My first Android Project, my first Kotlin Project (Java examples would help me to)

The Problem is this:
I have a TextView. I can change the text with code. But the Problem is it seems like my Activity must come to en end so that changes to the gui can happen.

```
myTextView.setText("x = $x") //this works once 

do{  
myTextView.setText("x = $x") //this doesnt work  
println("x = $x") //this works on standart io  
x++  
}while(true)  

do{  
myTextView.setText("x = $x") //this doesnt work until x reaches its limit   
x++  
}while(x<100)
```

What I have tried so far:
Start another thread with HandlerThread and try it there (doesnt work because "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.")

First my code was in onCreate, I realized that moving it to onResume was a better Idea, this way it atleast sets the text everytime I switch to the homescreen and come back. But thats still no solution.

The only workaround I have in mind is use Handler.post() on the same thread to create a loop but Im not sure if that would work, also it seems like the wrong way to do it, I would prefer the while loop the same way its also working with println() on standartio. Maybe there is some kind of refresh gui method which I need to call inside of the loop, but I dont know if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to do here in your app...If it's a simple `TextView` that counts up to 100, you're going to have to use a separate thread to do the counting and waiting if you don't want your app to be sluggish.

In android, an Activity's UI thread is essentially on a constant loop, waiting for user input and changes to views to be posted to a queue, which it handles sequentially. For that reason, it's recommended to keep business logic out of the main thread. Any long running operations on it will delay it from doing the job it's mean to -- calculate views appearances and refresh the screen 60 times a second.

One way to do this is with `AsyncTask`, a means of creating a new thread to run some business logic, which provides methods to update the main UI thread when it is done.

Create an inner class in your `MainActivity` that looks like this:

```
private class CounterTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        int count = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            try {              
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(i);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... status) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(status);
        int current = status[0];
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.counter_text_view);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(current));
    }
}
```

Then in the Activity's `onCreate` method, create and execute this task like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Run your counter task
    CounterTask task = new CounterTask();
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: if its simple than simply tell me how to use the second thread to change the textview without getting the "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." error. Also my workaround with Handler.post() works as long as I use the same thread, so instead of a while(true) the runnable calls Handler.post(this) in the and, this acts like a while(true) loop.

Comment: "if you don't want your app to be sluggish" thats not part of my question, I know that a loop doing nothing else than changing a textfield is not the best thing to do. This doesnt change the fact that I need to know how to do it since its basic knowledge.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the code to run your counter in an `AsyncTask`, which essentially takes care of creating and handling a separate thread to do a task, and runs code on the main thread when it has a progress update or when it's done.